# Is full load current line or phase current?

Tags: power, three-phase

If a question just asks for full load current, is this considered phase current or line current.  Do I need to consider if it is a wye or delta because of this?  With three phase power being `VL*IL*srt(3)` or `VP*IP*sqrt(3)`, I am not sure if I need to convert if given for example line voltage on a delta, but need phase current (if thats what i need) for full load rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motors and other 3-phase equipment are rated based on line current. The user does not need to know whether it is wye or delta unless there is a dual voltage Y/D rating. In that case, the rating plate should show 2 L-L voltage and 2 line current ratings.